# Onchange sessionStorage.clear() not working

Tags: javascript

I am clearing session on `onchange` but it's not working. I am having a text field, what I want is when something is filled on text filed and when I select `test` from `select` the data on text field which I filed earlier should be removed. For this I am using `sessionStorage.clear();` but it's not working.

My codes are here

```
function SesRes() {
    var x = document.getElementById("abc").value;
    if(x == "test") {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    }
}

<input type="text" value="">

<select id="abc" onchange="SesRes()">
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `sessionStorage.clear()` is not for you to clear text in textbox, [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: sessionStorage.clear() is to clear your sessionStorage objects you just need to document.getElementById("your text box id").value = "";

Answer (score 0):

No this is not the right way if you want to remove the data from your text input field.

Do something like:

```
<script>

function SesRes() {
    var x = document.getElementById("abc").value;
    if(x == "test") {
        document.getElementById("textField").value = "";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="textField" value="">

<select id="abc" onchange="SesRes()">
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```